# Can't figure out how to make my L298N work within my circuit

Tags: power, motor, integrated-circuit, l298

So I've been trying to use an L298N driver.

(Link to the one I bought: https://www.velleman.eu/downloads/29/vma409_a4v01.pdf)

And I've been utterly incapable of making it work. At first, it was built within a circuit, but that didn't work, so I've tried to make it the simplest possible to understand how it works, but there are no results.

So, in Motor A, I plugged in my Motor, two wires, nothing simpler.

In Motor B, nothing is connected.

In VMS, I plugged in the + of a 6V battery.

In GND, I plugged in the - of the battery.

In 5V, I didn't plug anything (and even when plugging something, it didn't work)

The 5v_EN jumper is placed.

In ENA and ENB, nothing is connected.

In Inputs 3&4, I didn't put anything; in inputs 1&2, I sometimes connected the +6V battery to see if the motor would run.

In the GND and +5V of that "line," I tried connecting them or not connecting them to the battery: but nothing worked.

Additional observations. When I connected one of Motor A's pins to my 12V battery's ground, the M would run. In all situations, but one. If I connected a positive to input 1 / 2, it would either make it run faster or stop, depending on the MA pin it was connected to.

This is killing me: I even bought a second L298N in case the first one had broken, but to no avail.

Here's a link to explain what I did in a diagram:
[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hsbj.jpg

The permanent lines = things I never changed

The dotted lines = thins I attempted

Red is for +

Green is for -

Thanks for any help <3

Edit: 6V battery not 12V

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141013/discussion-on-question-by-kron0s-cant-figure-out-how-to-make-my-l298n-work-with). Also, everyone needs to keep it nice.

Answer (score 0):

See here https://lastminuteengineers.com/l298n-dc-stepper-driver-arduino-tutorial/

That page deals with the breakout board that has a built-in 5 V regulator (if you have a bare chip, you will need to provide your own 5 V supply), but it has a good tutorial about the various pins and their functions.

Here's the thing: you may have damaged the chip(s) by applying 12 V to the 5 V logic pins. Or not. Depends on how robust the chip is. If you connect your chip as shown, and it still won't respond to controls, get a new one and make sure not to put 12 V in the logic level (5 V) pins.

Comment: I'd love to do this but I'm not actually doing it with an Arduino so I'm not sure that tutorial works? (I've already it, and most L298N resources on internet)

Am I reading the tutorial wrong maybe?

Comment: And another thing, the L298N I'm using seems to be different than the one in the tutorial (I can't find the red ones in Europe unfortunately), (I linked the one I used at the top of my post!)